# Screen goes off when playing videos in kubuntu

Tags: power-management

Screen Automatically goes dim and turns off when playing videos in Kubuntu 16.04.2 LTS (KDE Flavoured. No problem in Unity), even when playing local contents. There is no appropriate option in power management setting. How to override this for a particular application. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, the video application should handle this itself, but not all do, for all platforms.

You can manage it yourself with `Caffeine`.

You'll need to get it from a ppa:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:caffeine-developers/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install caffeine
```